# How to get the 'final url' of a Google AdWord's Ad?

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api

As Google AdWords changed from using the JavaScript function of getDestinationUrl, I've tried switching my AdWord's script to use urls().getFinalUrl(), however this only gives me the index page of the site, rather than the full URL.

Using getDestinationUrl now returns null, as expected, because it is deprecated.

How does one go about getting the final URL?

Currently I have:

```
selectedAdUrl = selectedAd.urls().getFinalUrl();
```

Returns:

> http://www.example.com/

Instead of the actual final URL, as in Google AdWords:

> http://www.example.com/an-example-page

Comment: `getFinalUrl()` is the correct method to use. Are you sure you are looking at the right ad when comparing the URL to the web interface? You can call `selectedAdUrl.getId()` and see whether it's the same ID as shown in Adwords.

Comment: That is the way to do it...